# Internal Presentation/Structure of a java object

Tags: java, class, object

I have created a `ClassA` in which i have `mapped` another `ClassB` which was `already mapping` to  `ClassC`.

So it's quite difficult for me to imagine the `internal structure/presentation` of the `object` of `ClassA`.

So i would like to know how to see the `internal presentation/structure` of the `object of ClassA.`

Comment: what do you mean by **internal structure/presentation ??** *bytecode*?

Comment: I think by `mapped` he means `extends`. And what he seems to wanna see is the `ClassA` like it had all its parent's methods/fields in it (something like the maven effective pom when there is a hierarchy of poms). But, this is just what I'm thinking...

Comment: http://www.codeinstructions.com/2008/12/java-objects-memory-structure.html

Comment: Can you present your imagination and where are you stuck with that

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about the memory layout of a Java object and how it integrates superclass fields, there is a [nice blog post that goes into details](https://web.archive.org/web/20140116073903/http://www.codeinstructions.com/2008/12/java-objects-memory-structure.html).

In a nutshell, the object of ClassA contains all the fields of parent classes ClassB and ClassC.

Objects stored in those fields (including arrays) are only contained as pointers to separate objects stored elsewhere, whereas primitives such as int are stored by value.